# Show Intent.ACTION_PICK in landscape

Tags: android, gallery, landscape

I am working on an app which let users choose photo from their gallery. The problem is I need to show the gallery in landscape only. Is it possible to do it?

I use this code:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RQC_GALLERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start any activity using explicit intent, you loose control from your application. Android finds out and application to perform that is described in intent object.

[Intent object attributes details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

From no where you can have control on next application regarding view.

If you want to fulfill specific requirement than make your own activity with Grid view and use  image adapter to set images.

[Here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) is one link which shows how to set images in adapter. It will help to design your code if necessary.